# Verify date lies in given range in specific format

Tags: javascript, date, protractor

I have a table column having date of births of different people in format Jan 1, 2014. I need to check whether all date of births displayed in this column lie in specific range like are in between Jan 1, 2012 to Jan 1, 2016. 
i ma having issues to pass my date range as a variable and compare values i get from table column in my protractor script. Below is piece of code I have written

```
    this.matchRange = function(value){
        this.names = element.all(by.repeater('row in jsonResponse').column(value)); 
    var startDate = 'Jan 1, 2012';
    var endDate = 'Jan 1, 2016';


    this.inResults = function(nameString){    
        return this.names.filter(function(name){
            return name.getText().then(function(testDate){
                console.log(testDate);  
                //expect(text).toMatch(nameString)
                return testDate >= startDate &&
                        testDate <= endDate;
                });
            }).then(function(filteredElements){
                // Only the elements that passed the filter will be here. This is an array.
                return filteredElements.length > 0;
                });
    };

    };
```

Comment: Why don't you simply convert your starting date, ending date into long format and similarly converting all your context date into long format and check whether they lie between starting,ending date

Comment: @ Vinod Louis Thanks for quick response, I am new to javascript, so don't know how to code what you are suggesting, can you please help me in that?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to parse a string like 'Jan 1, 2014' you should use a library or a simple function (3 lines of code). Once you have parsed the string to a date, they can be compared directly like:

```
if (dateA < dateB) {
  // dateA is before dateB
}
```

A simple function to parse the a date in MMM D, YYYY format is:

```js
// Parse date string like Jan 1, 2014
function parseMMMDYYYY(s) {
  var months = 'jan feb mar apr may jun jul aug sep oct nov dec'.split(' ');
  var b = s.match(/\w+/g) || [];
  return new Date(b[2], months.indexOf([b[0].toLowerCase()]), b[1]);
}
                               
console.log(parseMMMDYYYY('Jan 1, 2014').toLocaleString())
```